# Visual Studio Code Behind Missing After Windows 10 Error

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio-2015

Now I'm speechless, when i was working on my visual studio project, I got windows 10 error (blue screen said, my PC ran into problem.....).

After i restart, one of my code behind files is missing, no one single line in it!!

Now I don't know what to do, is there any way to retrieve it back?

If i open it with Notepad++,
it shows like this
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's all under control now.

I go to my visual studio project location, and found "Backup Files" folder there.
And I found a file there.
And it saved my time!!

Thanks